# How to deploy a Falcon MVC REST API in Azure Functions?

Tags: python, azure, model-view-controller, azure-functions, falconframework

I deployed my Falcon app in azure functions using bitbucket. But I cannot see any of the files in the function app. I also tried by pulling the repo to azure function folder but that didn't work either becuase my routes didn't work as expected. I use MVC architecture in my app. My run.py looks like

```
import falcon
from wsgiref import simple_server
from project.routes import *

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 5000
        httpd = simple_server.make_server(host, port, app)
        print("Serving on %s:%s" % (host, port))
        httpd.serve_forever()
```

Is there any way to deploy my app as it is or should I change the structure.

[Current folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIrHB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Functions is not an appropriate place to just place a web application and expect it to run as normal. It is a "serverless" framework, so having your app use a MVC architecture is a sign that your app is currently not a good fit for Azure Functions. In your application's current state, it is better suited for an [Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/).

Azure Functions apps should be built around small functions that are called in response to events. To make your application a better fit for Azure Functions, it would involve refactoring your application into individual functions, that are triggered by events such as HTTP requests, timers, and many others that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings).

Comment: Thank you. I could deploy same code in aws lambda without any setup. I used zappa.

Comment: What would actually trigger your Lambda code to run?

Comment: I use zappa to deploy the code to labda. "zappa deploy" will do the magic. An api call to any of the endpoints will trigger the code.

Comment: If your code is already structured to use zappa, then your application is likely in an appropriate architecture already. However, the only language we have a zappa-like experience for is C# using Visual Studio. You could port your app to Azure Functions by making each endpoint it's own function, but that would involve some manual effort. Also note that Python on Azure Functions is still in preview, so it is not recommended for production applications.

Comment: To work in zappa I didnt want to change the structure. zappa deployed my app as it is . But for azure I did split my code into functions and its working now. I installed python3 plugin and installed requirements using kudu console. Is it a good Idea to add more functions to the function app and deploy it in production or should I change to NodeJs ?

Comment: We generally don't recommend utilizing features that are in preview in production, as they may be removed or introduce breaking changes in the future. More official Python support should be coming to Functions 2.0 sometime in the future, but if you need stable support now, porting to NodeJs is probably the better option.